# Indexing columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I have a mysql_query . I was wondering which one to index.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM foo WHERE c=5 GROUP BY d
```

Maybe (c,d) or just c?

I have another similar.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM foo WHERE d=6 GROUP BY b
```

Maybe (d,b) or just d?

Another one here :

```
SELECT a FROM foo WHERE b=5 GROUP BY c
```

Here (a,b,c)?

My point is just to make the index which will cover three queries.. The best one here would be? and on which column?

Comment: i made a mistake.. I am editing

Comment: Why single index? What prevents you from creating several indexes?

Comment: I thought it would make more sense if an index can cover all of them..

Comment: Your queries are using different fields. Also I can't understand your 3-rd query (i.e. sense of it). There's no silver bullet for all cases. All should be analyzed and then decision could be done. Also there are MySQL restrictions (such as left-subset and single-index).

Comment: I think you would be better off focusing your efforts on matching the fields in your group by clause with those in your select clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to have one index to cover all use case.

MySQL can benefit from having index on order by/ group by columns. Saves it from doing filesort, temporary tables. My suggestions would be:

1) (c,d)

2) (d,b)

3) For the last one (a,b,c) would be unusable because it starts with a (column order matters). The proper index would be (b,c,a).

A bit explanation:

MySQL does the following:

1. filter the results (it needs b)
2. fetch it in order if have index on order by column or sort it (it needs c) (group by is the same)
3. return the columns in the select part (it needs a)

Another thing which is very important is the selectivity of your index. If for example you have a boolean with 50% true, 50% false MySQL won't use the index because it's easier to scan the whole table than traverse the index tree.

Answer (score 0):

For these three queries, you need three different indexes, one on `a`, one on `b`, and one on `c`.  These can be composite indexes, so they could be `a,b,c`, 'b,c,a`', and`c,b,a`.  But for each query, you need an index that has the one column in the`where` clause as the first column in the index.

MySQL uses the columns from the left -- the ordering of columns in an index matters.

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) actually explains this pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

For example... Consider just the first query.
You can index the "c" column only. But if you have a low selectivity for "c" (many many records with the same value for "c"), you can create a composite Index on (c,d) so the optimizer can avoid the sorting operation because, with an Index range scan, get the records already sorted.
For the third query, if you create an index on all the three columns you can avoid the Table access, because you get the result scanning the Index only.

But there are many variables that the Optimizer consider when chooses an execution path for your query, so the above are only few simple examples.

I'm not an expert about MySQL, so Gordon Linoff's answer may be more precise than my answer...